# angular-router-loader not working with npm linked packages

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack, lazy-loading

How can I make this loader work with an `npm link`ed dependency?

I have two projects `Project A`and `Project B`.
`Project B` is linked with `npm link` and it provides modules to `project A`.
The loader works fine when I lazy load on app.routing.ts of `Project A`:

```
...
{
    path: "my-apps",
    loadChildren: "project-b/my-apps/my-apps.module#MyAppsModule",
},
...
```

This correctly produces the instruction to lazy load the Module from `Project B`:

```
...
{
    path: "my-apps",
    loadChildren: function () { return new Promise(function (resolve)     { __webpack_require__.e/* require.ensure */(0).then((function (require) { resolve(__webpack_require__(1554)['MyAppsModule']); }).bind(null, __webpack_require__)).catch(__webpack_require__.oe); }); },
},
...
```

But...
On MyAppsModule (from Project B) I also have a lazy loaded child with the following instruction:

```
{
    path: ":slug",
    loadChildren: "./app-content/app-content.module#AppContentModule"
}
```

The thing is that the loader doesn't change the loadChildren of the module of`Project B`, it keeps the result intact, it produces the following:

```
{
    path: ":slug",
    loadChildren: "./app-content/app-content.module#AppContentModule"
}
```

Which ends up breaking my app with the message:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './app-content/app-content.module'.
```

For now I am "lazy loading" the module by doing the manual import of the module and using it in the `loadChildren` option, but as far as I know, that's not lazy loading a module per se. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Do you guys know how can I make this loader work with an `npm link`ed dependency?
Thanks in advance.

Webpack@2.2.1
angular-router-loader@0.5.0

Comment: When you `npm link` the package, you import the modules like they were an actual package, right?  Like `import { PackageBModule } from 'my-lib';`

Comment: Yes. On Project B I can use a normal import and everything works fine.
The problem comes with statements like `loadChildren` of Project B which needs the loader which is only working on Project A, but not on Project B.
How can I make Webpack to run its loader on both projects? :c